# Passing in Objects within an Object as Arguments to a Funciton

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm fairly stumped at a seemingly simple problem. I currently have an Object with multiple Objects inside it. I'm trying to dynamically take the objects (no matter the number) and pass them into a function as separate arguments. I don't want to manually call the function, as the number of Objects can vary depending on use.

I've included a code sample here (I've tried to simplify for readability): http://jsfiddle.net/z8mtc8jk/1/

Also the code is listed below:

```
var objectofObjects = {};
objectofObjects.obj1 = {key:"lol"},
objectofObjects.obj2 = {key:"rofl"},
objectofObjects.obj3 = {key:"lmao"};

console.log(objectofObjects);
console.log(Object.keys(objectofObjects).length + " is the number of objects inside the object");

function multipleArguments(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    console.log(Object.keys(objectofObjects));
}

//how can I add the objects within the objectofObjects as arguments to this function, 
//without gaving to call it like this...

multipleArguments(objectofObjects.obj1, objectofObjects.obj2, objectofObjects.obj3);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
multipleArguments.apply(this,Object.keys(objectofObjects).map(function(key){return objectofObjects[key]}))
```

Comment: A lot of the answers work for the scenario, but I really like how slick this solution is. Avoids the need to create an extra thing (array) and get's the job done just fine. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

pass the objects of object...

```
multipleArguments(objectofObjects);
```

and on your function, handle the objects inside it.

```
function multipleArguments(objcs) {
    for (var o in objcs){
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: When using the `in` operator one should assure that the key is a member of the object itself using `objcs.hasOwnProperty(o)` to not go over enumerable prototype properties. Also note that `o` is just the *key* not the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the objects accessable as members of another object you need to build an array containing the objects by iterating over its keys. Like so:

```
var args = [], keys = Object.keys(objectofObjects), i;
for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
   args.push(objectofObjects[keys[i]]);

yourFunction.apply(window, args);
```

Otherwise just store them in an array, so you have `arrayOfObjects` and directly use this for the `apply` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would place the objects in an array and then call the function with each index of the objects array as a parameter to the function.

```
for(int i = 0; i < objectsArray.length; i++) {
     myFunction(objectsArray[i]);
}
```